# remove %0A from string

Tags: java, android

how can i remove %0A from this string :- this is enter key code, which i need to remove from entire string. so how can i do this?

**input:-**

"NA%0A%0AJKhell this is test %0A"

**Output:-**

NAJKhell this is test

**Update**

```
String Comment = cmment_comment_edtx.getText().toString().trim();
String query = URLEncoder.encode(Comment, "utf-8");
System.out.println("comment edit is "+query);
query.replace("$0A", "");
String query2 = URLEncoder.encode(query, "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

example :

```
public class AP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "NA%0A%0AJKhell this is test %0A";
        System.out.println(text.replaceAll("%0A",""));

    }
}
```

Out put : 
NAJKhell this is test

Comment: i am trying but still not getting it.

Comment: String query = URLEncoder.encode(Comment, "utf-8"); try modifying it to String query = URLEncoder.encode(Comment.replaceAll("%0A",""), "utf-8");

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
String input = "NA%0A%0AJKhell this is test %0A";
String output =  input.replaceAll("$0A","");
```

Comment: i have checked it but still its not coming.

Comment: What do you mean with "not coming"? What do you get? What did you try? Show the code -- you may edit your original post for this purpose.

Comment: you have to use % instead of $

Comment: Strings are immutable `query.replace("$0A", "");` will not change the contents of `query`. And also see $ vs %.

Comment: I am trying it with % and $ but still not getting it.

Comment: `query.replace("$0A", "");` is a no-op and basicially does nothing.