# Issue with %0A replace in android

Tags: java, android

how can i remove %0A from this string :- this is enter key code, which i need to remove from entire string. so how can i do this?

**input:-**

"NA%0A%0AJKhell this is test %0A"

**Output:-**

NAJKhell this is test

i have tried

```
  String input = "NA%0A%0AJKhell this is test %0A";
  String output =  input.replaceAll("%0A","");
```

but still not get the output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove %0A from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095074/remove-0a-from-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replaceAll method takes a regex as parameter. Try to escape percent sign `\\%` I think it will work

```
String input = "NA%0A%0AJKhell this is test %0A";
String output =  input.replaceAll("\\%0A","");
```

Comment: Actually i need to replace %0A not a $0A.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Actually input.replaceAll("%0A",""); works fine and I have no idea why it's not working in your app. And so I recommend to escape character anyway, maybe that's the problem...

Comment: what you mean? check what? check if exists?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use Regex API, so it should look like this:

`input.replace("%A$", "");` - It will remove matching at the end of the `String` (because of $)

If you want to remove all `%A`, then

`input.replaceAll("%A", "");`